# How to derive a template class that needs a template type of a nested class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using OpenGL (C API) and encapsulating a few things in classes. Basically calls to `glGenX` generate `GLuint`s that are handles to the actual thing created. When you're cleaning up you should call `glDeleteX` on these handles.

What this means, is that for me to have a class that holds these (as well as encapsulates some other stuff specific to them) and be able to copy instances and pass them around, the class needs internal reference counting so that it only calls `glDeleteX` when there's no more references.

I've done this twice now and I'm looking at it for a third class. I can see quite a few classes I'm making need this; so I want to use templates to make it easier.

Here's an example of the original class with the reference counting to only call `glDeleteX` at the appropriate time:

```
class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(const GLuint texture) : m_data(new Data(texture)) {}
    Texture(const Texture& t) : m_data(t.m_data) { ++m_data->m_count; }
    Texture(Texture&& t) : m_data(t.m_data) { ++m_data->m_count; }
    ~Texture() { if(--m_data->m_count == 0) delete m_data; }

    void Bind(GLenum target, GLint location) const { /* do some stuff */;
    void Release() const { /* do some stuff */

    GLuint GetTexture() const { return m_data->m_texture; }

private:

    class Data
    {
    public:
        Data(const GLuint texture) : m_count(1), m_texture(texture) {}
        Data(const Data& data) : m_count(1), m_texture(data.m_texture) {}
        ~Data() { glDeleteTexture(1,&m_texture); }

        GLuint m_texture;
        unsigned int m_count;
    };

    Data* m_data;
};
```

Here's my attempt at templatizerating it:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class ReferenceCountedObject
{
public:

    ReferenceCountedObject(const Ts... args)
    :
        m_data(new Data(args...))
    {}

    ReferenceCountedObject(const ReferenceCountedObject& h)
    :
        m_data(h.m_data)
    {
        ++m_data->m_count;
    }

    ReferenceCountedObject(ReferenceCountedObject&& h)
    :
        m_data(h.m_data)
    {
        ++m_data->m_count;
    }

    virtual ~ReferenceCountedObject()
    {
        if(--m_data->m_count == 0)
            delete m_data;
    }

protected:

    class Data
    {
    public:

        Data(const Ts... args)
        :
            m_count(1),
            m_dataMembers(args...)
        {
        }

        Data(const Data& data)
        :
            m_count(1),
            m_dataMembers(data.m_dataMembers)
        {
        }

        virtual ~Data()
        {
            std::cout << "deleting base" << std::cout;
        }

        std::tuple<Ts...> m_dataMembers;
        unsigned int m_count;
    };

    Data* m_data;
};
```

The idea is that the internal `Data` class might need just one `GLuint` handle for class `Texture` but it might need three different ones for another type. So, that's why there's the internal `tuple`.

Now, the problem I have. Here's my original class now deriving from this templatized class:

```
class Texture : public ReferenceCountedObject<GLuint>
{
public:
    Texture(GLuint texture) : ReferenceCountedObject(texture) {}

    Texture(const Texture& t) : ReferenceCountedObject(t) {}

    Texture(Texture&& t) : ReferenceCountedObject(t) {}

    void Bind(GLenum target, GLint location) const { /* does that stuff */}
    void Release() const { /* does that stuff */ }

    GLuint GetTexture() const { return std::get<0>(m_data->m_dataMembers); }

protected:
};
```

How can I define the destructor of the base classes `Data`? So far, I've tried doing this:

Change the base class a bit:

```
template<class DataType, typename... Ts>
class ReferenceCountedObject
{
    /* ... */
protected:
    DataType* m_data;
};
```

So this way you can provide the DataType and just override the virtual destructor:

```
class Texture : public ReferenceCountedObject<Texture::TData,GLuint>
{
    /* ... */
protected:
    class TData : public ReferenceCountedObject::Data
    {
    public:
        ~TData()
        {
            std::cout << "deleting derived" << std::cout;
            glDeleteTextures(1,&std::get<0>(m_dataMembers));
        };
    };
}
```

But I can't instantiate `ReferenceCountedObject` with `Texture::TData` because `TData` is a part of what i'm trying to define.

How can I do this correctly? I concede that I could be going about this in a completely incorrect way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a `shared_ptr`? That's reference counted too, and it is simpler to pass around. Your class just has to deal with allocating and releasing the texture, and the shared_ptr does the refcounting and automatic deletion at the right time. Plus, this lets you use weak pointers for free.

You could define your internal Texture class, then do

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<internal::Texture> Texture;
```

so that external users only ever use the reference counted Texture.

Comment: I know i could. In fact that's what I was going before. But I'd prefer to figure out how to do the above.

Comment: Instead of parameterizing your refcounted class by the type of the data, parameterize it by the containing class (which has all the necessary acquire/release logic). You'll find it is a lot easier to implement.